# SQL - Determine the number of months of a contract period before and after a contract change

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I need your help again. It's about a SQL statement I'm at a loss.

As a basis I have a table with contract data for several customers. In this table you can see how long the contract for a customer is running and if there are any changes in the contract in the course of time.
If something changes, it is displayed as "TRUE" in the field "contract_value_change".

On this basis I have to calculate the number of months the customer had in the contract before and after the change. I have entered this result manually in the field "Factor". Do you have an idea how I can calculate this automatically with SQL? (I'm working with Redshift)

[image]

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "TEST_CUSTOMER" (
    "Customer_no" INT,
    "Month" TEXT,
    "Current_line_no" INT,
    "contract_duration_in_month" INT,
    "contract_value" INT,
    "contract_value_before" TEXT,
    "contract_value_change" TEXT,
    "FACTOR" INT
);
INSERT INTO "TEST_CUSTOMER" VALUES
    (100,'01-2020',1,12,100,'NULL','false',4),
    (100,'02-2020',2,12,100,'100','false',4),
    (100,'03-2020',3,12,100,'100','false',4),
    (100,'04-2020',4,12,100,'100','false',4),
    (100,'05-2020',5,12,80,'100','TRUE',8),
    (100,'06-2020',6,12,80,'80','false',8),
    (100,'07-2020',7,12,80,'80','false',8),
    (100,'08-2020',8,12,80,'80','false',8),
    (100,'09-2020',9,12,80,'80','false',8),
    (100,'10-2020',10,12,80,'80','false',8),
    (100,'11-2020',11,12,80,'80','false',8),
    (100,'12-2020',12,12,80,'80','false',8),
    (20000,'01-2020',1,6,2000,'NULL','false',4),
    (20000,'02-2020',2,6,2000,'2000','false',4),
    (20000,'03-2020',3,6,2000,'2000','false',4),
    (20000,'04-2020',4,6,2000,'2000','false',4),
    (20000,'05-2020',5,6,2500,'2000','TRUE',2),
    (20000,'06-2020',6,6,2500,'2500','false',2);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to want `count()` as a window function:

```
select c.*,
       count(*) over (partition by customer_no, contract_value) as factor
from test_customer c;
```

Actually, this is probably a gaps-and-islands problem -- if the contract value returns to a previously used value, then you probably want only the size of the "island".  If so, you can use the difference of row numbers to identify the "islands" and then use that:

```
select c.*,
       count(*) over (partition by customer_no, contract_value, current_line_no - seqnum) as factor
from (select c.*,
             row_number() over (partition by customer_no, contract_value) as seqnum
      from test_customer c
     ) c;
```